# I want to add a dart list to another list

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I want to create a list of entries the user makes, add that list to a list of lists . but each time I add a new list, all the sublists are updated to the new one

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:fooderlichapp/themes/models.dart';
 
 class Display extends StatelessWidget {   
 final TextEditingController
 textCont = TextEditingController();
 
   void add(list) {
     list.add(textCont.text);   }
 
   void addModelClass(list, model) {
     model = Model(name: textCont.text, list: list);
     ModelClass.modelList.add(model);   }
 
   void view() {
     var models = ModelClass.modelList;
 
     for (var model in models) {
       debugPrint(" ${model.list}");
     }   }
 
   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     List<String> list = [];
     var model = Model(name: textCont.text, list: list);
 
     return Container(
       child: Scaffold(
         body: Column(
           children: [
             TextField(
               controller: textCont,
             ),
             IconButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                   add(list);
                   debugPrint("added text successfully");
                 },
                 icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
             TextButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                   addModelClass(list, model);
                 },
                 child: Text("add text")),
             ElevatedButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                   view();
                 },
                 child: Text("display"))
           ],
         ),
       ),
     );   } }
```

and these are my models

```
    class Model {
      final name;
      Model({this.name, this.list});
      List<String>? list;
    }
    
    class ModelClass {
      static List<Model> modelList = [];
    }
```

my console outputs the following:

```
    flutter: added text successfully
    flutter:  [a]
    flutter: added text successfully
    flutter: added text successfully
    flutter:  [a, aw, aw]
    flutter:  [a, aw, aw]
    flutter: added text successfully
    flutter:  [a, aw, aw, wef]
    flutter:  [a, aw, aw, wef]
    flutter:  [a, aw, aw, wef]
    flutter:  [a, aw, aw, wef]
    flutter:  [a, aw, aw, wef]
    flutter:  [a, aw, aw, wef]
```